# "Clustering in trades" or "Clustering of trades"?

Tags: word-choice

Should I say "I examine the impact of clustering **of** trades by traders...." or "I examine the impact of clustering **in** trades by traders..."

Some people are telling me **of** but **in** sounds better to me.

Comment: Either will do. Possibly "in" might be better if you want to emphasis a larger number of clusters, rather than just a few. But it's not important.

Comment: They potentially mean different things. "Clustering of trades" describes different trades bunched together; "clustering in trades" could mean the same, or could mean bunches of people within individual trades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clustering of trades" is the correct form of this if it is a clustering of the actual trades that is being reference.

"Clustering in trades" could be used if you were referring to a clustering within a set of trades. However it is a clumsy sentence best to be avoided unless necessary